# How do I enable curl SSL on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, ssl, curl, terminal

I'm using Terminal on Mac OS X 10.11.2 and I can't process any https requests. I always get this error:

```
curl: (1) Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

I tried this but I get a "wrong directory" error:

```
./configure --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl
```

Any advice would be helpful.

**EDIT:**

This is the error I get when trying to install with ssl:

```
configure: error: OpenSSL libs and/or directories were not found where specified!
```

**SOLUTION:**

For Mac OS X 10.6 or later use this to enable SSL:

```
./configure --with-darwinssl
```

Comment: Have you tried `curl --ssl`?

Comment: "the installed libcurl version doesn't support this" I tried installing Homebrew but can't through Terminal since it's an https request.

Comment: what was the location of ./configure file in your case?

Comment: `curl -V` will list supported protocols (in addition to the version)

Answer (score 39):

The Homebrew team has recently removed all install options for the cURL formula, which means you will not be able to do `brew install curl --with-openssl` now. Instead, do `brew install curl-openssl`. Make sure to uninstall the old one with `brew uninstall curl` first.

Comment: This is the info I needed and it shouldn't be at the bottom of the page! Everyone else says to use the "--with-openssl" option which is no longer possible. Further, I also had to turn off my antivirus as it was blocking connections to be able to download the cURL packages.

Comment: just to add that after this you need to close the terminal and reopen it. A hour that I won't get back..

Comment: FYI - in 2021, it is proposed to install openssl curl with `brew install curl`, see this thread: https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/1268

Answer (score 13):

**Following steps helped fix the issue:**
(Note: libcurl will be rebuilt though)

```
# First simply remove curl and try reinstall with openssl:
brew rm curl && brew install curl --with-openssl # Rerun
```

If doesn't fix, download and rebuild libcurl with following steps, which helped me fix the issue

```
# Download curl from : https://curl.haxx.se/download.html
wget https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.58.0.zip  # or, wget https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-*.*.*
unzip curl-7.58.0.zip  # or, unzip curl-*.*.*

./configure --with-darwinssl  # However for Linux(ubuntu): ./configure --with-ssl 
make
sudo make install  # Rerun the program
```

Comment: This is a better answer than Ben's and deserves to be accepted. (Vadym Tyemirov's answer didn't work for me.)

Comment: (for others with similarly lackluster shell skills...) you need to cd into the unzipped curl directory before you can run ./configure --with-darwinssl

:-)

Comment: When run `./configure --with-darwinssl` there is an error occurred. `configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables`

Answer (score 7):

**SOLUTION:**

For Mac OS X 10.6 or later use this to enable SSL:

```
./configure --with-darwinssl
```

Comment: `-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory`- WHAT TO DO?  My Bounty:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39287906/error-while-installing-firebase-via-cocoapods/39300838?noredirect=1#comment65998448_39300838

Comment: where is curl installed on mac please ?

Answer (score 5):

Solved it by replacing standard curl with one with nghttp2 support (require brew)

```
brew install curl --with-nghttp2
brew link curl --force
```

include `--http2` when doing request

example:

```
curl --http2 https://www.example.com
```

or:

```
curl --header 'Access-Token: o.bFbpTuazstlUZXsnyTWTaJq0biZ' \
--http2 https://www.example.com/
```

Ref:
https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2016/08/01/curl-and-h2-on-mac/
https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2016/01/http2-curl-macosx/

Answer (score 1):

I made one rookie mistake by adding the URL within quotation marks (curl -v -k "https://URL.com"). After putting the link within apostrophes (curl -v -k 'https://URL.com') curl was accepting the https URL.

Comment: Removed the quotations and made the link to be like `curl https://example.com` instead of `curl "https://example.com"` and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that stumbles upon this in 2021 and later using Xcode 12+ attempting to build their project via commandline and doesn't want to rely on 'brew' or other package managers...

I was hitting the `./configure: No such file or directory` issue after getting the curl source from github.

**The source from github is missing the configure exec. that you need to generate your makefiles**

Apple provides the curl source along with required MacOS/iOS build settings in their Open Source Browser:

https://opensource.apple.com/source/curl/

https://opensource.apple.com/release/macos-112.html

1. Download & unpack the source
2. Set your env variables - [Apple Platforms (macOS, iOS, tvOS, watchOS, and their simulator counterparts)](https://curl.se/docs/install.html)

   `export ARCH=arm64`

   `export SDK=iphoneos`

   `export DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11.0`

   `export CFLAGS="-arch $ARCH -isysroot $(xcrun -sdk $SDK --show-sdk-path) -m$SDK-version-min=$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"`
3. cd to the /curl directory
4. run: `./configure --with-darwinssl`

My use case is building an iOS app on a hosted macOS build agent in Azure DevOps

Answer (score 1):

An updated solution in 2023 for Ventura. First you want to install openssl and then curl with brew:

```
brew install openssl
brew install curl
```

Afterwards you need to export the installed `curl` version to your `zsh` or whatever shell you using, with the following (change path to `/usr/local` if running on Intel):

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/curl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Then just check with `curl -V` the available protocols, where you should see https, sftp, etc.