# Opam init failure

Tags: ocaml, opam

I am new to Ocaml, and I am trying to run the following command on the Mac OS: `opam init`, and it throws following error. Can someone explain how to remove this error :

```
=-=- Fetching repository information =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-= 
[ERROR] Initialisation failed    
opam-version 1.2.2    
os           darwin    
command      curl --write-out %{http_code}\n --insecure --retry 3 --retry-delay 2 --compressed -OL https://opam.ocaml.org/urls.txt    
path         /var/folders/49/gjdw9yvx1jz647wmr1ghd2hc0000gn/T/opam-11172-d2d111    
exit-code    1    
env-file     /Users/suyashgupta/.opam/log/log-11172-ad8886.env    
stdout-file  /Users/suyashgupta/.opam/log/log-11172-ad8886.out    
stderr-file  /Users/suyashgupta/.opam/log/log-11172-ad8886.err
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: And the actual error message, which you didn't include for some reason: `# curl: (1) Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl`

Comment: Perhaps [this question and its answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34914473/409228) helps?