# Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Tags: ios, macos, google-maps, firebase, libcurl

Here's my Podfile content:

```
platform :ios, ‘8.0’
use_frameworks!

target 'Project-Name' do

pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

end
```

Same error occurs while adding `pod 'GoogleMaps'` into Podfile.

Error while running `pod install --verbose command` on Terminal:

```
[!] Error installing Firebase
[!] /usr/local/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/1t/102_4r0x1_3_5dlq8zdbm27r0000gn/T/d20160902-4388-1omozrn/file.tgz https://www.gstatic.com/cpdc/cc5f7aac07ccdd0a/Firebase-3.5.0.tar.gz --create-dirs --netrc-optional

curl: (1) Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

---

**Edit 1:** [How do I enable curl SSL on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34914473/how-do-i-enable-curl-ssl-on-mac-os-x)

`./configure --with-darwinssl` not working.

> -bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

---

**Edit 2:** [How do I enable https support in libcurl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015282/how-do-i-enable-https-support-in-libcurl)

This command `brew install curl --with-libssh2` is executed on terminal, but don't know what to do next:

```
UB:lib aspl$ brew install curl --with-libssh2 --verbose
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
No changes to formulae.

Warning: curl-7.50.1 already installed
UB:lib aspl$ curl --version
curl 7.48.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0) libcurl/7.48.0 zlib/1.2.5
Protocols: dict file ftp gopher http imap ldap ldaps pop3 rtsp smtp telnet tftp 
Features: IPv6 Largefile libz UnixSockets
```

This command not working:

```
$ otool -L /usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-http-push | grep curl
/usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
```

> /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/objdump: '/usr/local/bin/git/libexec/git-core/git-http-push': Not a directory.
>   fatal error: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool: internal objdump command failed
>   Binary file /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib matches

---

**Edit:3** Terminal command `which git` shows `/usr/local/bin/git`

---

**Edit:4** [Enabling HTTPS Support in Curl Installed Through MacPorts on OSX](http://naleid.com/blog/2009/03/16/enabling-https-support-in-curl-installed-through-macports-on-osx)

Running either `sudo port install curl +ssl` or `sudo port uninstall curl` says:

> sudo: port: command not found

And to install ports(MacPorts) following link is used, which again is an **HTTPS** link:

`$ curl -O https://distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/MacPorts-2.3.4.tar.bz2`

There also a download option of MacPort folder?

But what to do with that downloaded`MacPorts-2.3.4` folder?

**EDIT 5:** Force uninstall curl and installing again didn't work :(

```
$ brew uninstall curl
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.50.1... (366 files, 2.6M)
curl 7.46.0 is still installed.
Remove them all with `brew uninstall --force curl`.
$ brew uninstall --force curl
Uninstalling curl... (360 files, 2.6M)
$ brew install curl --with-libssh2 --verbose
Error: curl 7.50.2 did not build
Logs:
     /Users/aspl/Library/Logs/Homebrew/curl/01.configure
     /Users/aspl/Library/Logs/Homebrew/curl/01.configure.cc
     /Users/aspl/Library/Logs/Homebrew/curl/02.make
     /Users/aspl/Library/Logs/Homebrew/curl/config.log

These open issues may also help:
curl: migrate to openssl@1.1 https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/4591
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how you got to this broken version of curl in first place? Curl is already preinstalled on MacOS X, with https working just fine out of the box. Did you manually install or upgrade it to a newer version? If so - how did you do that?

Comment: I don't know..but is there is any way to restore or install the correct version of it?

Comment: this is guessing only. It could probably make things worse for you. But what I would try to do is to run `brew uninstall curl`. Then execute "curl" again.
maybe you'll then fall back to the default curl which comes with https support. If curl was completely removed, then you can do the ` brew install curl --with-libssh2 --verbose` afterwards. 

Again, this is risky. Brew might not be able to download anything without curl on your system. But that's the only suggestion I have :(

Comment: updated my question, it didn't work

Comment: with this new OS, now i am facing the same issue :) smh

Answer (score 5):

After I've installed `macOS High Sierra`, I've encountered the same issue when install firebase via `pod`.

The trick was to remove the curl and install it again:

```
curl --version // you will see the https protocol is missing, and the version would be 7.56.1 if you did try to update it before  
brew remove curl 
brew install curl --with-darwinssl // install with darwin instead of openssl 
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/curl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc // run this
```

after you should close & quit all terminal or iTerm, then open it again run `brew doctor` then run `curl --version` you should see `https` in the protocol list

Then you should be good to go :)

Comment: Could not reproduce the error as of now, but will mark it up as helpful!

Comment: Didnt work for me .. Warning: curl: this formula has no --with-darwinssl option so it will be ignored!

Comment: Great :). Works fine

Answer (score 3):

You might need to update git. One way:

```
brew install git
```

More [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cocoapods/FCnC83vutp4)

Comment: It didn't help, My libCurl Doesn't support 'https'. Bounty started!

Comment: More in this stackoverflow question and accepted answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015282/how-do-i-enable-https-support-in-libcurl

Comment: And according to this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34914473/how-do-i-enable-curl-ssl-on-mac-os-x - do ./configure --with-darwinssl

Comment: And according to https://justanothercoder.wordpress.com/2009/04/23/using-https-with-curl-on-mac-osx/ do  sudo port install curl @7.19.3_0+ssl

Comment: Since your curl is installed without https, according to https://justanothercoder.wordpress.com/2009/04/23/using-https-with-curl-on-mac-osx/, you need to do a sudo port deactivate before sudo port install or uninstall according to http://naleid.com/blog/2009/03/16/enabling-https-support-in-curl-installed-through-macports-on-osx

Answer (score 1):

Your URL is corrupt. Check for spaces or other characters at the beginning of the URL (before `http` or `https`).